# How do I hide a CCK Nodereference input widget in #after_build?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck, drupal-fapi

I like simplifying the node form. One of my tricks in the past has been to conditionally hide CCK elements on new node creation when I want to enforce some kind of default. One of my favorite tricks is to whisk away things put in place by the [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module. Unfortunately for me, it's recent move to an `#after_build`-based mechanism seems to be creating all kinds of collisions in how I can manipulate the widget.

#### This is what I used to do in `hook_form_alter()`:

```
  $form['field_my_nodereference_field'][0]['#type'] = 'hidden';
  $form['field_my_nodereference_field'][0]['#value'] = $form['field_my_nodereference_field'][0]['#default_value']['nid'];
  $form['field_my_nodereference_field'][0]['#parents'] = array('field_my_nodereference_field', 0, 'nid');
```

But when I try to play this game in `#after_build`, I run into errors with the `hidden` type's validation, or the `nodereference_autocomplete_validation`. I have *resorted to conditionally adding a CSS file*. This makes me sad.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden is not enough. Try this one:

`$form['field_my_nodereference_field'][0]['#type'] = 'nodereference_hidden';`

when the type is a CCK field you have to pass this format _hidden

for instance for a simple text field I used

```
$form['field_srt'][0]['#type'] = 'text_hidden';
```

or for a filefield field I used

```
$form['field_myfile'][0]['#type'] = 'filefield_hidden';
```